# All debian main commands broken by glibc

Tags: debian, python, glibc

Here is the thing. I'm lost.
I downgraded from Debian 10 buster (testing) to Debian 9 stretch (stable) by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list file.

I typed :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

All worked, lsb_release -a shown me a Debian 9 stretch version.

After that I typed these commands

```
apt-get clean
apt autoremove
```

Which shown me an error with python3.5-minimal and python3-minimal
So I tried to uninstall it

```
apt-get remove --purge python3
```

There starts the big troubles
Since this moment, it seems that all the GLIBC is broken.
At each basic command I write, there is this kind of output.

```
host:~# apt
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
-
host:~# wget
wget: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30)
wget: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0)
-
host:~# dpkg -i libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 407 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb ...
/usr/bin/perl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/bin/perl)
dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
```

I can't even connect to SSH anymore. I have a rescue console which allows me to write some commands but I can't download anything.

Is there something like a cache where I could get back python/glibc ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have definitely created [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). Depending on how mangled things are it maybe faster to backup any important data and reinstall from scratch. This time taking care to follow the advice of the Wiki and not mixing releases. I have found this [GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/christianbundy/0d982648cbfe3dd4350cee8ab9e53828) that could assist in saving your current install.

To get to your question, yes there should be a way for you to reinstall `python` and `glibc`.

Checkout `/var/cache/apt/archives` for `.deb` packages of `python` and/or `glibc`. For python, if you are running Debian Stretch on a 64-bit system it should be: `python3_3.5.3-1_amd64.deb`. Which can be downloaded manually from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3).

Once you have found the packages or downloaded them manually you need to run the following as root(sudo) to install them:

```
dpkg -i [Name of the Package].deb
```

If you are reinstalling any libraries you can download them manually from packages.debian.org. Once downloaded then you need to copy the library file into `/usr/lib` and run this command as root(sudo):

```
ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib
```

Now `apt` should no longer complain about these packages. Remember if you need to manually install the packages that you also grab the dependencies they list as well.

**If you continue to receive errors...**

Then you will need to follow user Avinash Raj's advice in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/430443).

Any package that `dpkg` is complaining about you need to run the following:

```
sudo dpkg -P [Name of Problematic Package]
```

After you have run the above command for each problem package that `apt` complains about then you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now the issue should be solved. If need be, reference [this guide](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3) and follow each of the steps to work your install back into working order.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!